# Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i am adding my todos list in my project but its give me Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined later its also says thats task.text is not define can any one help me with it plz

> here is my FormItems.js

```
const FormItem = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [task, setTask] = useState(props.task);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(props.index);
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
    const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState({});
    const date = new Date()
    const userId = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.uid);

    const saveTask = () => {
        setEditing(false);
        const payload = { id: currentTask.id, text: currentTask.text, completed: false, addedAt: selectedDate }
        const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(userId).child('tasks');
        dbtasksWrapper.child(payload.id).update(payload).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload });
        })
    }

    const completeTask = () => {
        const payload = { id: task.id, text: task.text, completed: true, addedAt: task.addedAt }
        const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(userId).child('tasks');
        dbtasksWrapper.child(payload.id).update(payload).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'COMPLETE_TASK', payload })
        })
    }

    const removeTask = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(userId).child('tasks');
        dbtasksWrapper.child(id).remove().then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_TASK', id: id })
            console.log('removed');
        })
    }

    const editTask = (task) => {
        setCurrentTask(task);
        setEditing(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTask(props.task);
        setIndex(props.index);
    }, [props])


    return (

        <li
            index={index}
            key={task.id}
            style={{
```

> here it says that Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined

```
                textDecoration: !task.completed ? 'inherit' : 'line-through'
            }}
        >
            <div>
                {
                    !task.completed ? <p></p> : <p className="alert alert-danger" >Task Completed </p>
                }
            </div>
            <div className="border">
                {editing ?
                    <div>
                        <input type='text' onChange={e => setCurrentTask({ ...currentTask, text: e.target.value })} value={currentTask.text} />

                        <DatePicker
                            className="input-group-prepend"
                            placeholderText="Enter task date "
                            selected={selectedDate}
                            onChange={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)}
                            showTimeSelect
                            timeFormat="HH:mm"
                            timeIntervals={15}
                            timeCaption="time"
                            dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy H:mm aa"
                            minDate={date}
                        />
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div>
```

here its also say cannot read task.text

```
<h3> {task.text} </h3>
                    <p>{task.addedAt && task.addedAt.toString()}</p>

                </div>
            }

            {editing ?
                <div>
                    <input type='button' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => saveTask(task.id)} value='Save Task' />
                    <input type='button' className='btn btn-link' onClick={() => setEditing(false)} value='Cancel' />
                </div>

                :
                <div>
                    <input className="btn btn-info btn-sm" type='button' value='CompleteTask' onClick={() => completeTask(task.id)} />
                    <input className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type='button' value='Remove Task' onClick={() => removeTask(task.id)} />
                    <input type='button' className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => editTask(task)} value='Edit Task' />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </li>
)
```

}

export default FormItem;

Comment: i din't read the whole thing, but maybe use `task && task.completed` instead of just `task.completed`?

Comment: @MoIsmat  i can understand it will be hard to understand like this so i am sharing repository kindly check this thank you git@github.com:jzebgul/hse-project.git

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously `task` can be `undefined`.

So you have to make sure, that your code can cope with this. For example like this.

```
textDecoration: (task && !task.completed) ? 'inherit' : 'line-through'

(task && !task.completed) ? <p></p> : <p className="alert alert-danger" >Task Completed </p>
```